# SQL how to get latest date and update every time it occurs (not using MAX)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get the latest date of starting event before it occurs again.

Data I have:

```
+-----+------------------+--------+--------+--+
| ID  |       DATE       | REGION | STATUS |  |
+-----+------------------+--------+--------+--+
| 200 | 2020-04-10 6:00  | USA    | START  |  |
| 200 | 2020-04-10 7:00  | USA    | ACTIVE |  |
| 200 | 2020-04-10 13:00 | USA    | STOP   |  |
| 200 | 2020-04-10 15:00 | USA    | START  |  |
| 200 | 2020-04-10 16:00 | USA    | ACTIVE |  |
| 200 | 2020-04-10 19:00 | USA    | ACTIVE |  |
| 200 | 2020-04-10 20:00 | USA    | STOP   |  |
+-----+------------------+--------+--------+--+
```

What I want to make:

```
+-----+------------------+--------+--------+------------------+
| ID  |       DATE       | REGION | STATUS | LAST_START_DATE  |
+-----+------------------+--------+--------+------------------+
| 200 | 2020-04-10 6:00  | USA    | START  | 2020-04-10 6:00  |
| 200 | 2020-04-10 7:00  | USA    | ACTIVE | 2020-04-10 6:00  |
| 200 | 2020-04-10 13:00 | USA    | STOP   | 2020-04-10 6:00  |
| 200 | 2020-04-10 15:00 | USA    | START  | 2020-04-10 15:00 |
| 200 | 2020-04-10 16:00 | USA    | ACTIVE | 2020-04-10 15:00 |
| 200 | 2020-04-10 20:00 | USA    | STOP   | 2020-04-10 15:00 |
| 200 | 2020-04-10 20:00 | USA    | STOP   | 2020-04-10 15:00 |
+-----+------------------+--------+--------+------------------+
```

I want to create another column with the latest start time and record it, then update it whenever it happens, and keep that value from there until start appears again.

What I tried:

```
SELECT id, date, region, status, last_start_date
 FROM (SELECT t1.*,
             MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'START' THEN date END) OVER (PARTITION BY id,region) as last_start_date
             FROM table1 t1
     ) t1
    GROUP BY id,region,status
```

This didn't work since MAX only returns the latest one showing up, which isn't what I was trying to do:

```
+-----+------------------+--------+--------+------------------+
| ID  |       DATE       | REGION | STATUS | LAST_START_DATE  |
+-----+------------------+--------+--------+------------------+
| 200 | 2020-04-10 6:00  | USA    | START  | 2020-04-10 15:00 |
| 200 | 2020-04-10 7:00  | USA    | ACTIVE | 2020-04-10 15:00 |
| 200 | 2020-04-10 13:00 | USA    | STOP   | 2020-04-10 15:00 |
| 200 | 2020-04-10 15:00 | USA    | START  | 2020-04-10 15:00 |
| 200 | 2020-04-10 16:00 | USA    | ACTIVE | 2020-04-10 15:00 |
| 200 | 2020-04-10 20:00 | USA    | STOP   | 2020-04-10 15:00 |
+-----+------------------+--------+--------+------------------+
```

What would be the right approach here to achieve my goal?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry, didn't notice about that. I'm using sql-server. Will edit tag, thanks a lot for the how to make nice looking tables too. Thought excel would do the job, haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost did it - you just need to add `order by` clause:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [ID] INT
   ,[DATE] DATETIME2(0)
   ,[REGION] CHAR(3)
   ,[STATUS] VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([ID], [DATE], [REGION], [STATUS])
VALUES ('200', '2020-04-10 6:00', 'USA', 'START')
      ,('200', '2020-04-10 7:00', 'USA', 'ACTIVE')
      ,('200', '2020-04-10 13:00', 'USA', 'STOP')
      ,('200', '2020-04-10 15:00', 'USA', 'START')
      ,('200', '2020-04-10 16:00', 'USA', 'ACTIVE')
      ,('200', '2020-04-10 19:00', 'USA', 'ACTIVE')
      ,('200', '2020-04-10 20:00', 'USA', 'STOP');

SELECT *
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'START' THEN date END) OVER (PARTITION BY id,region ORDER BY [DATE])
FROM @DataSource;
```

[image]

Comment: I have a group by id, region, status condition. I think this won't work because of group by status condition.

Comment: is what I was trying to do not possible if I have to keep group by status condition there?

Comment: This will give you your desire output, what's the issue?

Comment: My issue was that I couldn't fully understand how ORDER BY after partition by worked the way I wanted. The GROUP BY condition at the end combine those as one whole thing, MAX(~~) will look for the maximum value, in this case,  latest start date and this will be partitioned by for each id and each region. From my query, MAX will return a single value, so I thought MAX is not a right approach. How did just ORDER BY [DATE] find the cases whenever START happens and update it's value? Just trying to understand what's happening here

Comment: I'm sorry about adding another condition, but does making GROUP BY id, region, status, DATE(DATE) will make it different question? to look for every day's latest start date and of course if START happens more than once in a day, update value just like the question

Comment: question was more of a general example to find solution to the question I have. I'm sorry about not writing another condition from the beginning.

Comment: We are using the `PARTITION BY` clause to perform grouping. Adding the `order by` clause makes the rows ordered by date, and perform the `max` aggregate only for the row with small date to the current one.  It's like using `ROWS BETWEEN` with `OVER` clause - very powerful syntax for specific cases.

Comment: Check this example - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#d-specifying-the-rows-clause

Comment: Thanks, finally understood how this works. All thanks to you, learned some new skill that looks really useful from now on as well